# XML formatting for later parsing in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, split

I'm using XML to hold some settings, so let's go with the following example:

```
<PermissionLevels>
    <Permission Name="MyPermission 1" Bases="XXX" />
    <Permission Name="MyPermission 2" Bases="XXX" />
</PermissionLevels>
```

So the XXX is my problem. I will have several base permissions, e.g. "Read, Create, Delete", and I know C# has the `.Split` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so I could probably try it with "," as a delimiter. I could also have child nodes to `<Permission>`.

Is there a correct way to do it? With correct I mean the following: I'm not sure whether I should use LINQ (`XDocument`) or the regular `System.Xml` variant (`XmlDocument`) and I am not sure if some different way might be better to handle.
With `.Split` I will have to take the `node.Attributes["Base"].Value`, split it and do a `foreach` for all elements in the array - maybe LINQ is smarter and can do something differently?

Sorry for my rambling, this is just not my domain. The question actually is: When I have multiple values for one attribute, do I concatenate them with e.g. a ",", or do I do it differently (e.g. with child nodes of the object)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer child nodes. Attributes are meant for scalar (single) values.

Also, this way your source code in C# with LINQ will be simple and that's good.